# Bundling a different version of the embedded JPA provider in your EAR

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I'm developing a web application that is being deployed to a GlassFish 3.1 instance.

Eclipselink 2.4 was recently released which has some nice additional features as highlighted in this [blog post](http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2012/05/jpql-vs-sql-have-both-with-eclipselink.html), that I would really like to take advantage of in my app.

I've bundled the EclipseLink 2.4 library into my application (It sits in the `/lib` folder), but Glassfish continues to use the embedded Eclipselink 2.3 library.

How do I make GlassFish use my bundled EclipseLink provider?

Answer (score 0):

You need change GlassFish classloader order([enter link description here](http://creativemohan.com/?p=196)) or update GlassFish EclipseLink library ([enter link description here](https://blogs.oracle.com/GlassFishPersistence/entry/updating_eclipselink_bundles_in_glassfish))

Comment: Has someone tried that? I was trying to replace the eclipselink jars and glassfish would never start again :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Updating EclipseLink to a newer version in existing GlassFish V3 installation](https://blogs.oracle.com/GlassFishPersistence/entry/updating_eclipselink_bundles_in_glassfish)